# how to assign unique color to the group of turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I am working on my simulation. One of the feature of my simulation is to assign unique color to the group of turtles.

In my simulation, groups are formed dynamically. So I don't know the exact number of groups of turtles being formed in the simulation. I want to assign unique color to each group of turtles.

I can generate unique color but the problem is  some of them look similar because of the same color variant. Can anyone tell how I can generate distinguish unique color?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not just pick some distinct-looking colors yourself, by hand?

Answer (score 0):

While generating the unique colour, map it with already generated unique colours. And instead of checking exact match, provide a minimum distinguishing differences. So that, any colour which is within that range of existing colour must not be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the unique color's number value is anything between this number sets: 5, 15, 25, ... , 135

You should've seen the pattern and you could transform it into some formula like this:

```
set color (random 13 * 10) + 5
```

With that formulia, I think it should get the random number between a set of {5,15,25,35,...,135}

Comment: or `set color one-of base-colors`